# How do you download the server certificate from a database in C++?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to download the SSL certificate from a remote database server. I have the information of the database server such as the host name, port number, username, and password.

I know how to download a SSL certificate from a public host such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) by using OpenSSL, but when I try to do that for the database server, BIO_do_connect() fails because of the missing info.

I use ODBC to connect and perform queries on the database.

So, how would I be able to get authenticated and download the SSL certificate using OpenSSL in C++?

Comment: Different database servers have different protocols and different ways how SSL is used in these protocols.  So the answer to your question depends on the specific database system used - which is unknown.

Comment: I connect to these databases using ODBC.

Comment: ODBC is only a programming API to abstract away implementation differences for databases. It is not a wire protocol. But knowledge of the database specific wire protocol is needed here.

Comment: Oh okay got it. I'm using SQL Server 2014. So, there's no generic way to download SSL certificates from servers?

Comment: Correct, there is no generic way which covers all databases. For MS-SQL server there is a similar question - see [OpenSSL: Fetching SQL Server public certificate](/questions/34981859/). There is for a example [a python implementation](https://gist.github.com/lnattrass/a4a91dbf439fc1719d69f7865c1b1791) linked in one answer. Have a look at it to implement similar things in C++.